# Java floating point, why 2.15 - 1.10 = 1.0499999999999998?

Tags: java

```
double amount1 = 2.15;
double amount2 = 1.10;
System.out.println(amount1 - amount2);

-------

1.0499999999999998
```

Why above code produces 1.0499999999999998

Comment: Try out `0.1 + 0.2` should return smth like `0.30000004`. Its because how floating point numbers and binary work. Maybe this is interesting for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0&t=230s

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/